# SARIMA residual analysis question

Tags: arima, residuals, acf-pacf

I am new to ARIMA and here I have a question about residual analysis. My data is seasonal ARIMA data, and after fitting a non-seasonal difference and a seasonal difference to my data, I get the following residual AC and PAC plots. Is my residual a white noise? what is the acceptable residual plot to make it a white noise? 
[image]

[image]

[image]